# Collision Detection in Java 2D Not Working Properly

Tags: java, 2d, collision

So basically for the past age and a half I've been trying to get this box guy (player) that when he collides with another box, he stops moving in the direction he collided with the box in. It is sort of successful but at seemingly random moments if I'm moving up and hit the box on the player's left side it may spaz into the box it collided with and flies down. It is the same in every direction.

```
public int checkCollision(ID id){
    for(int i = 0; i < handler.obj.size(); i++){ //Cycles through all the objects
        GameObject go = handler.obj.get(i); //Stores a temp GameObject
        if(go.getID() == id){ //Checks if the id matches and if so do the collision stuff.
            if(getBoundsT().intersects(go.getBounds())){
                System.out.println("collided top");
                y = go.getY() + go.getHeight();
                velY = 0;
                return 0; //Top side
            }
            if(getBoundsB().intersects(go.getBounds())){
                System.out.println("collided bottom");
                y = go.getY() - height;
                velY = 0;
                return 1; //Bottom side
            }
            if(getBoundsL().intersects(go.getBounds())){
                x = go.getX() + width;
                velX = 0;
                System.out.println("collided left");
                return 2; //Left Side
            }
            if(getBoundsR().intersects(go.getBounds())){
                System.out.println("collided right");
                x = go.getX() - width;
                velX = 0;
                return 3; //Right Side
            }
            if(getBounds().intersects(go.getBounds())){
                System.out.println("collided on all sides");
                return 4; //All the sides
            }
        }
    }
    return 5; //No Collision
}
```

The checkCollision method is called 60 times every second. The getBounds(l/r/u/d) function just returns a rectangle on either the left, right, top (up), or bottom (down) side corresponding to the letter. Id is just what the player is colliding with. In this scenario it is the wall so wherever it says id it is just the wall. (I've made sure the rectangles don't go out of the area they are supposed to.)

I've tried everything I can think of so any help would be appreciated! (This is my first question sorry if it's written horribly)

Edit: Intersecting Code (getBounds) This is in the GameObject class that all objects inherit.

```
public Rectangle getBoundsB() {
        return new Rectangle((int)(x + (width/2) - (width/4)), (int)(y + height/2), (int)(width / 2), (int)(height / 2));
    }
    public Rectangle getBoundsT() {
        return new Rectangle((int)(x + (width/2) - (int)(width/4)), (int) y, (int)width / 2, (int)(height / 2));
    }
    public Rectangle getBoundsR() {
        return new Rectangle((int)(x + width - 5), (int)(y + 5), 5, (int)(height - 10));
    }
    public Rectangle getBoundsL() {
        return new Rectangle((int)x, (int)(y + 5), 5, (int)(height - 10));
    }

    public Rectangle getBounds() {
        return new Rectangle((int)x, (int)y, (int)width, (int)height);
    }
```

and in the tick method (called every 60 seconds):

```
checkCollision(ID.Wall);
```

Comment: How are you checking if an intersection happens. It could be specifying that it intersects at more than one point and the first if statement that matches gets returned. So if it interests at the left and bottom it might return bottom first.

Comment: I'm checking if the player's left side intersects with the object's collision box and if so stop the x movement and x velocity.  I'm doing this for each side* except for the up and down ones replacing x with y.

Comment: Are you only checking if the left edge intersects the right edge? Or are you doing if left edge intersects with any edge?

Comment: I'm checking if the left edge intersects with any edge

Comment: What is ID, because you are using == on it. If it's an enum, then that's ok, but otherwise use .equals

Comment: ID is an enum (ID.Wall)

Comment: So I've done something similar in the past. What was happening is that it checked in sequential order. So when I did my intersect check, it showed that the left edge was intersected with both left and bottom. If it is happening in yours, it would always return in top, bottom, left, right order. So even if you intersect from the left, it may return bottom.

Comment: So then it spazes through the block because it thinks it's colliding w/ the top or bottom instead of the left?

Comment: It could be. Could you provide your intersect code too?

Comment: So it looks like this is exactly what's occurring.  Imagine, lining up two equal size rectangles side by side. It would intersect on 3 possible sides even if only by 1 pixel.

Comment: Why does would it intersect on all three sides? (I'm new at this sort of stuff)

Comment: Try to imagine the rectangle that is drawn by your bounds. The bounds of the bottom and left intersect with each other. So if you collide on the left side since the bounds share a common intersection, it would trigger the intersection check at the bottom first before it reaches the left check in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image below shows the 3 sides of the rectangle against a wall. If I press the rectangle against the wall the left corner of the blue and green line touches the wall, and the red line touches the wall. So what's happening is because you check top first, it sees that at that single point there was an intersection and returns true for Top intersection instead of left.

[image]

I think you could fix this modifying how you get your top/bottom bounds. Maybe by subtracting 1 from the width you return your bounds at.

Comment: That's not the problem :(  My collision boxes aren't drawn like that.  I took a screenshot of the way it looks.  The boxes to pay attention to are the ones in red.  Those are the collision box: http://imgur.com/51tMGkq.  (Both blue boxes are essentially the same).

Comment: In your getBoundsB/T/L/R methods, are you extending the bounds of the box or the object it collided with as it's hitbox?

Comment: Yes, I'm checking if the left side collides w/ any side - Do you think if I check if the left side collides w/ the right side it'll work better? Edit: Nope it didn't :(

Comment: @Cornchip I noticed you have print outs specifying which side of the collision code triggered. When you hit from the left side, what does the print out say?

Comment: It says the left side if I'm hitting on the left side until I spazz into it, it then says it collided on the top and bottom after slightly going through it. I'll quick show you: https://youtu.be/GzEQMD2SyWY

Comment: How are you moving the square relative to when are you checking for collisions? It seems like it doesn't catch the collision and the square ends up moving too far past the bounds.

Comment: I'm add player movement, (x += velX; y += velY;) then checking collision. Edit: Switching them does nothing but make it worse ;(

Comment: Rather than switching them, what you may need to do is to check ahead to make sure it's a valid move before shifting the box. If it's not valid then back track on the movement. I'm not sure, but in your collision code, it stops the velocity but doesn't stop the box from moving into the walls since you've already added the movement to the X/Y values?